# use distance between two points to determine relative location

Tags: javascript, distance, triangulation

I have a pair of fixed location sensors (infrared) that bounce a signal off of a reflector to a fixed receiver (all 3 devices are on a single PCB, [transmitter, receiver, transmitter]). The data given to me by the API of this device is the range from each sensor to the reflector (hand, table, anything).

My question is this: using the above data, how can I determine a relative X position of the reflector. I am fairly sure this is a trivial problem but my brain is drawing a blank.

The data ranges from 0 to 240 for each sensor.

```
var pos = 120 + (ranges.left - ranges.right);
pos = 100/240 * pos;
pos = Math.round(pos);
```

This was my initial attempt, the idea being it gives me an x position from 0 to 100. This sort of works, in a jumpy way - but I'd like a more refined method.

While there are a lot of questions on here regarding finding distances between known points, I've not found one doing the reverse (which is what I want to do).

EDIT:

The two dark circles are the transmitters, the light circle is the receiver. The square is the reflector. The line is the X axis, I would like to know the position of the square along that line. But please note that the line may be closer or further away from the sensor at any given point.

[image: Bad Drawing]

Comment: Can you draw a picture?  That would help me visualize your setup.

Comment: when you say `relative X position`, what is the X position relative to? To the receiver?  To  the PCB?  I think **couchand**'s suggestion would be helpful, this sounds like the geometry would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have updated the question

Comment: Just a quick point - the ranges reported are the distances to the two sensors, so in this setup it may report something like (60, 50) (bottom, top). If the square was further away on the Z axis - but still in the same position along the X axis, the ranges may be reported as (150, 140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works out by looking at triangles...

Using the diagram...
[image]

S is the separation of the two transmitters, R the range to the target, A,B are the distances measured by the device and 'x' is what we're trying to find.

By Pythagoras:   (here A^2 denotes A squared)

```
A^2 = R^2 + x^2       or   A^2 - x^2 =     R^2
```

and

```
B^2 = R^2 + (S+x)^2   or   B^2 - (S+x)^2 = R^2
```

rearrange this to

```
     A^2 - x^2 = B^2 - (S+x)^2
     A^2 - x^2 = B^2 - S^2 - 2Sx - x^2      expand (S+x)^2
     A^2       = B^2 - S^2 - 2Sx            lose x^2 from both sides
A^2 - B^2 +S^2 = -2Sx                        rearrange
```

finally:

```
   A^2 - B^2 + S^2
   _______________  =  x
        -2S
```

ta da !

I did a quick check measuring on paper and I think it's correct. Another quick check is if A is the same as B, in which case it boils down to:

```
  -S^2 / 2S  == -S/2  == 1/2 way between the transmitters, which is right.
```

**Edit: following comment below...**

Note that the final formula only involves A,B and S. We need S (the distance between transmitters) because this completes the triangle A/B/S and therefore scales the output value. You could use a fixed value for this but the output would not relate directly to the scale of the A or B values. However, you could use s=100 giving...

```
         A^2 - B^2 + 10000
 x =     _________________  
              -200
```

or, in javascript:

```
var pos= ((ranges.left*ranges.left)-(ranges.right*ranges.right)+10000)/200;
```

this will give a value between 0..100 for the object being directly somewhere *between the two sensors* e.g. if both sensor values are, say 42, we get:

pos = (42*42 - 42*42 + 10000) /200;     // answer = 50

If the object is directly in front of sensor A, we could have values:

pos=  (100*100 - 140*140 + 10000)/200;  // answer = 2

or directly in front of B:

pos=  (140*140 - 100*100 + 10000)/200;  // answer = 98

Further along your 'x' axis will obviously get larger values in one direction and go -ve in the other direction. 
I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Nice attempt - but this assumes I know the value of R, which I do not. the only values I have are A and B (I can probably work out S from the device specifications, or just try different values)

Comment: No, look again... the final formula does NOT use R to calculate x. It is only in the initial terms to demonstrate how we define the triangles A/\R and B/\R. You *could* rearrange the formula to calculate R as well if you wanted.

Comment: This mostly did the trick, I discovered that other factors were causing me problems (the ranges were in fact not distance to target, but closeness to target, and they are sensitive to light, and colour of the reflector) - however your code worked well. Thanks